# How can I write consecutive named files in Java?

Tags: java, filenames, string-formatting

I have a method for saving a File, but I don't know how to save files with consecutive names such as `file001.txt`, `file002.txt`, `file003.txt`, `filennn.text`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following line of code to create the filenames.

```
String filename = String.format("file%03d.txt", fileNumber);
```

Then you will just use that string to create new files:

```
File file = new File(filename);
```

The following code will create files numbered 1 - 100:

```
for (int fileNumber = 1; fileNumber <= 100; fileNumber++) {
    String filename = String.format("file%03d.txt", fileNumber);
    File file = new File(filename);
}
```

Or, you will need to have a static variable that you increment every time you create a new file.

```
private static int fileNumber = 0;
public void createNewFile(){
    String filename = String.format("file%03d.txt", fileNumber++);
    File file = new File(filename);
}
```

Comment: or "file%03d.txt" to match the pattern in the question

Comment: and fileNumber should probably be static so we don't forget where we are from invocation to invocation.

Comment: mmm and what would fileNumber be?

Comment: @Valeria, well, it depends how you need to number them.  If you are creating the files in a loop, then you can use the loop variable.  Updating the answer.

Comment: @Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson, the files are created every time I click a button, can that be named a loop?
(sorry, I'm new with Java)

Comment: @Valeria, you will want to use my second suggestion then.  Keep the number of files created as a variable in the class where you are creating files.

Comment: I'd rather loop and check for existing files to make it re-entrant/safer.

Comment: @Thilo, agreed.  It depends what the files are for.  It might be ok to over-write the files.  But, if you cannot over-write files, then you should check to see how high you got last time, and start there.

Comment: I realize verbosity is the norm if you want to be taken seriously as a Java programmer because, well, verbosity rules but... How is that easier to read than *File file = new File( "file" + filenum.getAndIncrement() + ".txt")* ?  Where *filenum* is an *AtomicInteger* because moreover your example isn't threadsafe?

Comment: @Web, well, code I post on the site is generally meant to be educational, and not copy-pasted straight into production code.  Your example is good, and readable.  My code attempts to teach as well as follow the spec that the asker posted.

Answer (score 0):

It may be desirable for you to skip over writing to a file if it already exists.

This could be done easily by placing the following at the beginning of the for loop proposed by Justin 'jjnguy' Nelson, for example:

```
if(new File(fileName).exists())
{
    continue;
}
```